# how to object to chunk array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to object to chunk array in javascript??

```
const objectData = {
101: {name: 'abc', year: '24'},
102: {name: 'bs', year: '64'},
103: {name: 'cd', year: '74'},
104: {name: 'ef', year: '54'},
105: {name: 'ew', year: '34'},
};
```

how to convert chunk array?

```
chunkData = [
[101: {name: 'abc', year: '24'}, 102: {name: 'bs', year: '64'}],
[103: {name: 'cd', year: '74'}, 104: {name: 'ef', year: '54'},],
[105: {name: 'ew', year: '34'},]
];
```

please help me

Comment: your required format is invalid - so, the short answer is, there is no way to produce that

Answer (score -1):

## Group Objects in Array

The question describes a format that is invalid `[ 102: {...}, 103: {...} ]` is not a valid value; the elements must either be keys in one object, or are individual objects themselves (curly braces are missing).  As an attempt to answer the question, both scenarios will be addressed:

1. An array of one object with two keys: `[{ 102: {...}, 103: {...} }]`
2. An array of two objects with one key: `[ {102: {...}}, {103: {...}} ]`

The following examples use "AoA" to describe an array of an array as demonstrated in the original question, though a single array with an element as a single array should warrant further inspection by the author.

#### 1. AoA of 2-key Objects

This creates an array of arrays, each with an object that has two keys.

```js
const objectData = {
  101: {name: 'abc', year: '24'},
  102: {name: 'bs', year: '64'},
  103: {name: 'cd', year: '74'},
  104: {name: 'ef', year: '54'},
  105: {name: 'ew', year: '34'},
};

const chunkData = Object.entries(objectData).reduce((arr,t,i)=>{
  let chunk = (i%2 == 0) ? [{}] : arr.pop()
  chunk[0][t[0]]=t[1];
  arr.push(chunk)
  
  return arr
},[])


console.log( chunkData )
```

#### 2. AoA of 2 Objects

Group objects into 2-element arrays, by using `%2` to batch them together:

```js
const objectData = {
  101: {name: 'abc', year: '24'},
  102: {name: 'bs', year: '64'},
  103: {name: 'cd', year: '74'},
  104: {name: 'ef', year: '54'},
  105: {name: 'ew', year: '34'},
};

const chunkData = Object.entries(objectData).reduce((arr,t,i)=>{
  let chunk = (i%2 == 0) ? [] : arr.pop()
  chunk.push({[t[0]]: t[1]})
  arr.push(chunk)
  
  return arr
},[])


console.log( chunkData )
```

Comment: Please qualify downvotes so corrections will be made